# Stitching together overlapping arrays in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, diagonal

Given two numpy arrays (matrices)

```
A = np.linspace(1,9,9).reshape(3,3)
B = np.linspace(10,18,9).reshape(3,3)
```

We can combine them into a block diagonal matrix by doing:

```
from scipy.linalg import block_diag
block_diag(A,B)
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., 10., 11., 12.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., 13., 14., 15.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., 16., 17., 18.]])
```

I am wondering if there is a straight forward way to define the following 'overlap' type matrix from A and B:

```
array([[ 1.,      2.,         3.,       0.],
       [ 4.,  (10.+5.)/2,  (6.+11.)/2,  12.],
       [ 7.,  (13.+8.)/2,  (14.+9.)/2,  15.],
       [ 0.,      16.,       17.,      18.]])
```

So instead of placing A, B on the diagonal, we allow them to overlap to some degree, and elements in the overlap get averaged. In general, I'd like to specify the degree of overlap, so in this example the degree of overlap would be 2. I'd also ideally want to keep the sparse structure, as opposed to constructing the entire array.

Comment: What do you define as "straight forward"? I doubt there is a builtin function for that, but you could do it with like 3 lines of code? Have you tried?

Comment: @Julien do you mean that it is easy to construct the explicit matrix with 3 lines of code? I know that is easy, the hard part is maintaining the sparse structure. As in, I don't want to actually built the full matrix, I want to have some sparse representation like block_diag. Yes it should be 0. not 7.

Comment: I have 0 experience with sparse matrices. but yes I'd say regular matrices could be coded in an easy handful of numpy lines. Ans so the seasoned sparse user would know how to did it in that case too?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it for regular matrices:

```
overlap = 2
pad_A = len(A)-2
pad_B = len(B)-2
ZerosA = np.zeros((pad_A,pad_A))
ZerosB = np.zeros((pad_B,pad_B))
Sum = block_diag(A,ZerosA) + block_diag(ZerosB,B)
Denom = block_diag(np.ones_like(A),ZerosA)+block_diag(ZerosB,np.ones_like(B))
Out = np.where(Denom>0, Sum/Denom, 0)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  0. ],
       [ 4. ,  7.5,  8.5, 12. ],
       [ 7. , 10.5, 11.5, 15. ],
       [ 0. , 16. , 17. , 18. ]])
```

Again no experience with sparse matrices, but I would assume the structure of this solution should translate well to sparse representation given it just uses block definitions too?